# ansible - couldn't resolve module/action 'amazon.aws.s3_object' / The module amazon.aws.s3_object was not found in configured module paths

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, ansible, amazon-s3

Per [requirements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/s3_object_module.html#requirements), I did installed all the required packages, however `amazon.aws.s3_object` is one of those things:

- `couldn't be resolved/found`
- `was not found in configured module paths`

---

step(s), I used to re-produce my issue:

```
% docker run -it debian:stable-slim bash
root@6140e6e2c06c:/# apt-get -qq update && apt-get -yqq install ansible python3-boto3 python3-botocore
root@6140e6e2c06c:/# uname -a
Linux 6140e6e2c06c 5.15.49-linuxkit #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Sep 13 07:51:32 UTC 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux
root@6140e6e2c06c:/# cat /etc/debian_version
11.7
root@6140e6e2c06c:/# ansible --version
ansible 2.10.8
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
root@6140e6e2c06c:/# python3 --version
Python 3.9.2
root@6140e6e2c06c:/#
root@6140e6e2c06c:/# ansible localhost -m amazon.aws.s3_object
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
localhost | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The module amazon.aws.s3_object was not found in configured module paths"
}
root@6140e6e2c06c:/#...
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/s3_object_module.html):

> This module is part of the [amazon.aws collection](https://galaxy.ansible.com/amazon/aws) (version 5.4.0).
>
> ...
>
> To install it, use: `ansible-galaxy collection install amazon.aws`

```
root@befa2662325b:/# ansible-galaxy collection install amazon.aws
root@befa2662325b:/# ansible localhost -m amazon.aws.s3_object
localhost | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "missing required arguments: bucket, mode"
}
```

---

Alternatively, instead of working with the horribly outdated versions of Ansible and related packages, install Ansible via pip.

```
root@2b8f31d78667:/# apt install python3 python3-pip
root@2b8f31d78667:/# python3 -m pip install ansible
root@2b8f31d78667:/# ansible --version
ansible [core 2.14.6]
root@2b8f31d78667:/#
root@2b8f31d78667:/# ansible-galaxy collection list |grep aws
amazon.aws                    5.5.0
root@2b8f31d78667:/# ansible localhost -m amazon.aws.s3_object
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
localhost | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "missing required arguments: bucket, mode"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Context:

- Your installed version is Ansible 2.10.8

```bash
shell> root@6140e6e2c06c:/# ansible --version
ansible 2.10.8
...
```

- The collection *amazon.aws* should be installed in Ansible 2.10.8 by default. See the [build](https://github.com/ansible-community/ansible-build-data/blob/main/2.10/ansible-2.10.build)

```python
amazon.aws: >=1.2.0,<2.0.0
```

- The module *s3_object* was added in the collection *amazon.aws* version 1.0.0. See the [source](https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/blob/main/plugins/modules/s3_object.py)

```
DOCUMENTATION = r"""
---
module: s3_object
version_added: 1.0.0
short_description: Manage objects in S3
```

- You haven't created any [configuration](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file) yet

```bash
root@6140e6e2c06c:/# ansible --version
ansible 2.10.8
  config file = None
```

---

Solution:

Make sure the collection is included in the [COLLECTIONS_PATHS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#collections-paths). For example,

```bash
shell> ansible-config dump | grep COLLECTIONS_PATHS
COLLECTIONS_PATHS(/scratch/tmp7/test-353/ansible.cfg) = ['/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

```bash
shell> find /home/admin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages -name s3_object.py
/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/action/s3_object.py
/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/modules/s3_object.py
```

Change the path depending on where you [installed](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible) the collections.

---

Note:

It is possible to install more versions of Ansible collections simultaneously. It's up to you to configure the path to the version you want to use.

Comment: the collection is indeed shipped with the Debian Ansible package, but this module is not included.

Comment: Maybe because the shipped version of the collection is version `1.4.0` ...